# Check if user exists on FIrestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function that use SignInWithGogle to Sign In/Up an user

```
 void _signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    print('user email here $user.email');
    setState(() {
      if (user != null) {
        _success = true;
        _userID = user.uid;
        final userToSubmit = User(
            email: user.email,
            id: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName,
            owner: false,
            favorites: null);
        print('USER ID USER ID USER ID ${user.uid}');
        DocumentReference dbRef =
            Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid);
        dbRef.get().then((value) {
          print('VALUE EXISTS? ${value.exists} y VALUE $value');
          value.exists ?
            _goToHomeScreen(user)
          :
          dbRef
              .collection('prf')
              .document('profile')
              .setData(userToSubmit.toJson())
              .then(_goToHomeScreen(user));
        });
      } else {
        _success = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem is that when the user logOut and then login it sets the new Data and the user lost everything they have like favorites and so on... I thought that checking if the document exists should resolve the problem, but despite the document is there exists returns false.
This is the piece of code I'm talking about

```
DocumentReference dbRef =
                Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid);
            dbRef.get().then((value) {
              print('VALUE EXISTS? ${value.exists} y VALUE $value');
              value.exists ?
                _goToHomeScreen(user)
              :
              dbRef
                  .collection('prf')
                  .document('profile')
                  .setData(userToSubmit.toJson())
                  .then(_goToHomeScreen(user));
            });
          }
```

Why it returns false even if the user.uid and the document exists? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution I implemented is this:

```
 FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    try {
      firebaseUser = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    } finally {
      final userToSubmit = User(
          email: firebaseUser.email,
          id: firebaseUser.uid,
          name: firebaseUser.displayName,
          owner: false,
          restauranteAdded: false);
      DocumentReference dbRef =
      Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(firebaseUser.uid).collection('nameOfTheCollection').document('documentName');

      dbRef.get().then((data) {
        data.exists ? _goToHomeScreen(user) :  
          _createUser();
      });
```

This way I check if user document exists in my Firestore Database and if not it creates it.

Comment: Don't you think this will increase the read count on Firebase? Like every-time user tries to login via Google, you have to check whether that user is available in the Firestore collection and that in turn will affect the read count, right?

Comment: You will use this only when you create a new user. So it will be only 1 extra read, well 2 if you count the rules check.

Answer (score -1):

There is a lot going on. In general, you're not updating any `state` object with the `setState()` method. `setState` is used to tell a widget that some `state` has changed--and it's called *synchronously* with the change, but here where you're just checking to see if a document exists and nothing is changing, it's not needed.

Also it doesn't appear that you're actually returning a `user` object at all, so this code as I read it will always return `false`.

1. You should remove `setState` here altogether (not needed for what you're doing)
2. Run a sign in method that returns the user object you want do do things with.
3. Access your db once you know you have a signed in user (i.e. w/ uid of signed in user)

Here is an option to try:

```
//Create a User class so that you don't have to call FireBase in your methods.
class User {
  User({
    @required this.uid,
    this.email,
    this.displayName,
  });
  final String uid;
  final String email;//these are whatever you want
  final String displayName;
}

//put sign in methods into an abstract class. Don't have to, but keeps code flexible if you don't stay with firebase
abstract class AuthBase {
 //add in other signin methods as needed
  Future<User> signInWithGoogle();

}

//Implement AuthBase in class Auth
class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

//Get a User from Firebase User
  User _userFromFirebase(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return User(
      uid: user.uid,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
    );
  }

//your signinWithGoogle method
Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
  //where User is the class you've created
  GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();

  if (googleUser != null) {
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    if (googleAuth.idToken != null && googleAuth.accessToken != null) {
      final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential( //await your instance of FirebaseAuth
        GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        ),
      );

      return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user); //your signed in firebase user that you can do stuff with uid, email, displayname, etc.
    } else {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'ERROR_MISSING_GOOGLE_AUTH_TOKEN',
        message: '',
      );
    }
  } else {
    throw PlatformException(
      code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
      message: '',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well this code Does actually return an user object, it's only a piece of code and it's working fine, but you're right about the setState, the dbRef logic should be isolated. However the question is about How to check if document ID exists in the database.

Comment: Okay. I was trying to address why you were returning "false" which was last part of the question.

Comment: the line print('USER ID USER ID USER ID ${user.uid}'); returns userID, so like I said the problem is not the auth flow. however I found a way to check if document id exists.